# How would I run this method with the main method?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, program-entry-point, void

This is is the code:

```
public class monkeyTrouble {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        monkeyTrouble s = new monkeyTrouble();
        s.trouble(false, false);
    }

    public boolean trouble (boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) {
         if (aSmile == true && bSmile == true){
             return true;
         } else if (aSmile == false && bSmile == false) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
    }

}
```

---

How can I run the boolean method in the main method so it will correctly run?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here by run correctly.  What exactly are you trying to make it do.  if you want to do something with the value that trouble returns, declare boolean b = s.trouble(false,false);

Comment: I am using eclipse and in order to run a program in this compiler. I have to have a main method. What do I put in the main method in order to use my trouble method?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are already running your method; you aren't displaying or storing the result. You could print the result like

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    monkeyTrouble s = new monkeyTrouble();
    System.out.println(s.trouble(false, false));
}
```

Also, your method could be simplified like

```
public boolean trouble (boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) {
     return aSmile == bSmile;
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you! Also another question: what would I have to change in order to make this method ask me for input on what the boolean values are?